Flatten batched data in IoT rule for uploading to a DB
I'm attempting to publish batched telemetry data and upload as individual records to a DB (e.g., Timestream)
My data looks something like this:
{
  timestamp: 100,
  temps: [1, 2, 3],
  voltage: [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
}

where the data is taken 1 time unit apart.
The goal is to upload this to a database (such as Timestream) as individual records that look like this:
| timestamp | temp | voltage |
| --------- | ---- | ------- |
| 100       | 1    | 1.1     |
| 101       | 2    | 2.2     |
| 102       | 3    | 3.3     |

I'm not experienced with AWS services.  Is there a natural way to accomplish this using IoT rules?
From looking through the IoT rule syntax, it doesn't appear so.  After some googling, it sounds like I might need a Lambda to accomplish this.  Is a Lambda the right way to approach this?  If so, are there any examples of this?
